# How to destroy a arraylist with foreach

Tags: c#

```
GameObject Lightwall;   // It's here we store the name tag 
GameObject LightWalls;  //the name of the tag
Object[] LightWall; 

public GameObject wallPrefab;
Collider2D wall;  // this is the wall which is surrounding the player
Collider2D walls; //had to make a new because of this error `wall' conflicts with a declaration in a child block

Vector2 lastWallEnd;

void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D co)
{
    if (co != wall && co.tag != "Power Up")
    {
        healthP1--;

        if (healthP1 == 1)
        {
            transform.position = Vector3.zero;

            var Lightwall = GameObject.FindWithTag("LightWalls");
            foreach (var walls in LightWall) //NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object this is the error that i'm getting: Playermovmnet.OnTriggerEnter2D(UnityEngine.Collider2D co)
            {
                Destroy(Lightwall);
            }

        }
```

My problem is the code `foreach (var walls in LightWall)`. I have tried to just use the other wall but this error showed up: `wall conflicts with a declaration in a child block`. The only way to get rid of it was to make another one that is similar.

Comment: Change `Destroy(Lightwall);` to `Destroy(walls);`

Comment: Like Valentin above said is the right way but as you said in your code comment - the NullReferenceException - then the problem is in your previous line returning a null reference "var Lightwall = GameObject.FindWithTag("LightWalls");"

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to destroy using the wrong parameter , use `wall` instead of `LightWall`

```
if (LightWall != null)
{
    foreach (var walls in LightWall) 
    {
         Destroy(walls);
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that `var Lightwall = GameObject.FindWithTag("LightWalls");` Lightwall is a GameObject.

Comment: so i should get rid of var Lightwall = GameObject.FindWithTag("LightWalls");

Comment: If you get rid of that , how will you get a list of walls to destroy ?

Comment: The code is working but the walls are not destroyed when my player is reset to the original place.

Comment: which may mean that this code , should be run on a different event trigger before a player's position is reset

Comment: ty all but i have no idea where else to put it, but thanks anyway